# To register in CASE of request SQL(oracle) a condition which is executed when " not data found"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a request, it works completely, and without problems. Here is the query :.

```sql
 WITH rowsel as (select   OBL_TAREDAT   ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO   from
                                (select  OBL_TAREDAT    ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO from  WAYBILLS where EXTERNAL_ID = json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data.external_id') 
                                 and OBL_TTN is null))
SELECT CASE
WHEN  json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data_weight.stable') = 'false'  THEN 81
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'   THEN 41
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'     THEN 21
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'     THEN 62
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'    THEN 61
ELSE 0 END
FROM rowsel
```

In it I look for 1 record on external id, and depending on the data which I find to it by means of cases I choose which script I want to receive on an exit.
I want that when I do not find any record on external id, I could enter "if the counter = 0 then 1". I tried my option but it didn't work, I'll be grateful for the help.

```sql
 WITH rowsel as (select  id, OBL_TAREDAT    ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO   from
                                (select id, OBL_TAREDAT ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO from  WAYBILLS where EXTERNAL_ID = json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data.external_id') 
                                 and OBL_TTN is null))
SELECT CASE
WHEN count(rowsel.id) = 0 THEN 1
WHEN  json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data_weight.stable') = 'false'  THEN 81
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'   THEN 41
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'     THEN 21
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'     THEN 62
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'    THEN 61
ELSE 0 END
FROM rowsel
group by rowsel.id, rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  ,rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT,rowsel.DIRECTIONID,rowsel.TARE,rowsel.BRUTTO
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `UNION ALL` and `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
WITH rowsel as (select   OBL_TAREDAT   ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO   from
                                (select  OBL_TAREDAT    ,OBL_BRUTTODAT,DIRECTIONID,TARE,BRUTTO from  WAYBILLS where EXTERNAL_ID = json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data.external_id') 
                                 and OBL_TTN is null))
SELECT CASE
WHEN  json_value ( {{CLOB}}, '$.data_weight.stable') = 'false'  THEN 81
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'   THEN 41
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '1'     THEN 21
WHEN rowsel.OBL_TAREDAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'     THEN 62
WHEN rowsel.OBL_BRUTTODAT  is null and rowsel.DIRECTIONID = '-1'    THEN 61
ELSE 0 END
FROM rowsel
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rowsel)
```